# why does CSS Calc() function requires whitespaces before and after "+"or "-" operators ONLY

Tags: css

Ex:`calc(10px + 2px);` is correct
but
`calc(10px +2px);` gives out an error
or
`calc(10px - 2px);` is correct
but
`calc(10px -2px);` gives out an error. However, this doesn't apply to other operators

Comment: How does it otherwise know that the `-` is supposed to be a minus and not part of a negative number

Comment: That's why I included the `+` operator example because it shouldn't matter in that case

Comment: Because the operation might get a little more complicated than `calc(10px +2px);`, like `calc(5px+-1px);` can't really work (it's `calc(5px + -1px);`? So it's always better to have whitespaces, even it looks nice.

Comment: @Amr - it doesn't matter in the case of `+` for technical reasons. It's just required for consistency with `-`. The CSSWG resolution is here: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2008Nov/0147.html - see the last resolution on the page. The discussion about the real reason why the hyphen is problematic begins here: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2008Mar/0173.html (it's not about negative numbers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the `+` operator, the operation might get a little more complicated than `calc(10px + 2px);`. I mean something like `calc(5px + -1px);` is actually more complicated, and it can't be `calc(5px+-1px);`.

For the `-` operator, how CSS is supposed to know whether the `-` is the minus operator or a part of a negative number? I mean logically though.

Also, the whitespaces make the code nice to read, for humans.

Learn more about the CSS [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function in the documentation.

Comment: So is it just to look nice and parser constraints? Because unlike any other language, the whitespace don't really matter

Comment: "*For the - operator, how CSS is supposed to know whether the - is the minus operator or a part of a negative number? I mean logically though.*" By using basic parsing rules, like 'is this symbol immediately preceded by another symbol'.